# EntityFramework using linq request with group by and having

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to make this request with LINQ :

```
SELECT esi, id FROM `ouvrage` group by esi having count(*) > 1
```

My result is :

```
from doo in dp.ouvrage
group doo by new {doo.ESI, doo.ID} into grouped
where grouped.Count() > 1
select new { grouped.Key.ESI, grouped.Key.ID };
```

But this request return me 0 result but it must returned me 3 results

Why ?

Thank you for help me please.

Comment: `group by esi`  is not the same as `by new {doo.ESI, doo.ID}`. There are other ways to pass the ID along.

Comment: should not be as `group by esi` ?

Comment: Which SQL dialect allows the `id` field to be selected when it's not in your group expression and not an aggregate? What do you expect to get as id?

Comment: I expect to have id column

Comment: We can't see what you have in the table, but it stands to reason that the 'id' column would be unique for each row.  In which case, if you are grouping by 'esi' then you would expect multiple different id values for each row.  As stated above, that is not valid SQL.  you'd either have to remove ID from the select list or add it to the group by list.  The fact you're grouping by it in linq is probably why you get nothing - you're just getting single rows as you're grouping by id.